# Disable Google Drive context menu outside Google Drive folder

Tags: windows-7, context-menu, google-drive

When I am in my Google Drive directory on my Windows 7 machine, I can right-click any folder or file and see a [context menu entry](https://plus.google.com/+GoogleDrive/posts/72FDua3Tr31) to directly share the item or view it online. This is useful functionality.

Unfortunately, the context menu entry also appears for every folder across my entire system, just with the "Share..." and "View on the web" entries grayed out. It does not appear on any actual files.

How do I get rid of the context menu outside my Google Drive directory without losing the functionality while inside it? I am comfortable editing the registry if needed, but I don't know what key is being referenced (or what to do from there).

Comment: I would be surprised if that is possible ...

Comment: Dropbox is set up so you can suppress the context menu outside the sync directory, so it can be done. I'm not sure how though, so you may be right that I can't.

Comment: Dropbox has a special setting built in by the Dropbox developers themselves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a tool like ShellExView to view your context menu items, locate the Google Drive shell, open in the registry and disable from there. Be SURE to backup your registry and use at your own risk!

Comment: Could you break this answer out into a few clear steps, perhaps using the numbered list option in the WYSIWYG editor?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking for here.  If you mean in regards to how to use ShellExView exactly, I just played with it a bit and used what was on their website as reference: http://www.winhelponline.com/xp/slowrightclick.htm

Comment: This will remove it inside of the Google Drive folder as well.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find the shell extension using *ShellExView*, but you can navigate to:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Drive

and then rename the **contextmenu64.dll** or **contextmenu.dll** file.

***However this will most likely remove it inside the GDrive folder too.***

Comment: So what does the "However" statement mean exactly?

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to keep the functionality inside the folder and renaming the DLL does break the whole thing. It's a thought though I suppose.

Comment: Answer is outdated, current Drive application does not include those files anymore.